# Disconnect client socket in java

Tags: java, android, ios, sockets, windows-phone

I am developing a chat project to serve iOS, Android, WindowsPhone application,

I got bit problem:
How can server socket detect disconnected client???,

Explain:

1. when i used java console, i click X button of windows then server socket detected disconnected client and i remove it in user online list
2. when i use client on cell phone application and i shutdown Wifi and 3G to disconnect server socket but server socket did not detect disconnected client.

How to solve this problem??

P/S: i can not use clientSocket.setSoTimeout() because client always connect to server socket, it only disconnect when network problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then you are asking how can one know when connection between Server and client is disconnected.

You can use one maintenance Thread which will keep checking from `List<ServerSocket>`, It can call `serverSocketObj.isClosed()`, and if it finds so it can remove that `ServerSocket` item from list.

You can use one boolean field to manage running tasks(client chat serving) in `ThreadPoolExecutor`, where it will check if connection is still alive to be served. That maintenance Thread can set this field appropriately.